# Problems with multiple panels in a single notebook page

Tags: python, wxpython

I am creating a program to calculate D&D scores. I have all the backend done, and I want to get the GUI done now.

What I am trying to do here is have a static panel for certain buttons (next, previous, ok, cancel, etc.). The panel is not cooperating.

I want to try to get it on the bottom right (where next/previous buttons traditionally are). This panel can go in the notebook `sizer` or in the sizer `sizerMain` I have made for everything else in `step_1`.

Let me know if you have any questions. I am very new to wxPython and I hope you can deal with my code... :)

Code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx

class step_1(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)

        # Create initial sizers and panels
        ## Main sizer, containing both panels
        sizerMain = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        ## For the main control area
        panelControl = wx.Panel(self,2)
        sizerControl = wx.GridBagSizer(hgap = 4,vgap = 4)
        ## For buttons
        panelBtn = wx.Panel(self,1)
        sizerBtn = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        # Add widgets
        ## Main content area
        lblTitle = wx.StaticText(self,label = "Pick Scores")
        sizerControl.Add(lblTitle,pos = (0,0),
                         flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.BOTTOM,
                         border = 5)

        btnRoll = wx.Button(self,label = "Roll!")
        sizerControl.Add(btnRoll,pos = (0,1),span = (1,5),
                         flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,border = 5)
        ### Radio boxes
        #### Radio button tuple
        rboxPick = ["Default","Strength","Dexterity","Constitution",
                    "Intelligence","Wisdom","Charisma"]

        self.lblRoll1 = wx.StaticText(self,label = "0")
        sizerControl.Add(self.lblRoll1,pos = (1,0),flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.rboxRoll1 = wx.RadioBox(self,label = "Roll One",choices = rboxPick)
        sizerControl.Add(self.rboxRoll1,pos = (1,1),span = (1,5),
                         flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT,border = 2)

        self.lblRoll2 = wx.StaticText(self,label = "0")
        sizerControl.Add(self.lblRoll2,pos = (2,0),flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.rboxRoll2 = wx.RadioBox(self,label = "Roll Two",choices = rboxPick)
        sizerControl.Add(self.rboxRoll2,pos = (2,1),span = (1,5),
                         flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT,border = 2)

        self.lblRoll3 = wx.StaticText(self,label = "0")
        sizerControl.Add(self.lblRoll3,pos = (3,0),flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.rboxRoll3 = wx.RadioBox(self,label = "Roll Three",choices = rboxPick)
        sizerControl.Add(self.rboxRoll3,pos = (3,1),span = (1,5),
                         flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT,border = 2)

        self.lblRoll4 = wx.StaticText(self,label = "0")
        sizerControl.Add(self.lblRoll4,pos = (4,0),flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.rboxRoll4 = wx.RadioBox(self,label = "Roll Four",choices = rboxPick)
        sizerControl.Add(self.rboxRoll4,pos = (4,1),span = (1,5),
                         flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT,border = 2)

        self.lblRoll5 = wx.StaticText(self,label = "0")
        sizerControl.Add(self.lblRoll5,pos = (5,0),flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.rboxRoll5 = wx.RadioBox(self,label = "Roll Five",choices = rboxPick)
        sizerControl.Add(self.rboxRoll5,pos = (5,1),span = (1,5),
                         flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT,border = 2)

        self.lblRoll6 = wx.StaticText(self,label = "0")
        sizerControl.Add(self.lblRoll6,pos = (6,0),flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.rboxRoll6 = wx.RadioBox(self,label = "Roll Six",choices = rboxPick)
        sizerControl.Add(self.rboxRoll6,pos = (6,1),span = (1,5),
                         flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT,border = 2)

        ### Instructions
        self.tcLogger = wx.TextCtrl(self,style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        sizerControl.Add(self.tcLogger,pos = (7,0),span = (1,6),
                       flag = wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT,border = 5)

        self.tcLogger.AppendText("""Instructions

1. Click the "Roll!" button up top.
    - Scores will be placed in the empty slots on the left side.

2. Look at the scores and decide where you want to put them.

3. Click the correct label for each score.
    - Make sure you only assign one score to one ability.

4. Click "Assign" to finalize the assignment.""")

        ## Button area
        self.btnPrev = wx.Button(self,label = "Previous",size = (90,28))
        self.btnAssign = wx.Button(self,label = "Assign",size = (90,28))
        self.btnNext = wx.Button(self,label = "Next",size = (90,28))
        sizerBtn.Add(self.btnPrev)
        sizerBtn.Add(self.btnAssign)
        sizerBtn.Add(self.btnNext,flag = wx.RIGHT|wx.BOTTOM,border = 5)

        self.btnNext.Disable()
        self.btnPrev.Disable()

        # Set and fit sizers, panels, etc.
        ## Growable rows and columns
        sizerControl.AddGrowableCol(1)
        sizerControl.AddGrowableRow(7)
        ## Finalize sizers and panels
        panelControl.SetSizerAndFit(sizerControl)
        panelBtn.SetSizerAndFit(sizerBtn)


        ### Final sizer to hold everything
        sizerMain.Add(panelControl,2,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_TOP|wx.ALL,border = 5)
        sizerMain.Add(panelBtn,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM|wx.RIGHT,border = 5)
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizerMain)
        self.Layout()

        # Bind events (as needed)


class step_2(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        txtOne = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        txtTwo = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(txtOne, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(txtTwo, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class step_3(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        txtOne = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        txtTwo = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(txtOne, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(txtTwo, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

####
# create a button class here for later, don't worry about it now
####

class main_frame(wx.Frame):
    """Main Frame holding the main panel."""
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        # Build the menu bar
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuFile = wx.Menu()

        menuFileQuit = menuFile.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, text="&Quit")
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit,menuFileQuit)

        menuBar.Append(menuFile, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)

        # create the page windows as children of the notebook
        nbPage1 = step_1(nb)
        nbPage2 = step_2(nb)
        nbPage3 = step_3(nb)

        # add the pages to the notebook with the label to show on the tab
        nb.AddPage(nbPage1,"Page 1")
        nb.AddPage(nbPage2,"Page 2")
        nb.AddPage(nbPage3,"Page 3")

        # finally, put the notebook in a sizer for the panel to manage the
        # layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Center()
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = main_frame(None,-1,size = (1000,1000),title = "D&D Charcter Creator")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: *Let me know if you have any questions.* I have a question: What is **your** question? If the code gives an error when you run it, tell us what that error is. If the code does not do what you expect, tell us (a) what you expect and (b) what you are seeing. We're happy to help, but we're not doing your work for you, and we aren't mind readers (last time I checked, ``import mindreading`` gave an import error).

Comment: It doesn't give any errors when running, but `panelBtn` is located behind `panelControl`, which I don't want it to be. Where I want `panelBtn` is below `panelControl` on the right side (similar to a program installer..). Does that make sense? Thank you for being patient..

Comment: wxglade will give you a higher quality of life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got parenting problems!

For example, you want the widget `self.lblRoll1` to be on the `panelControl` therefore you should make it a child of it.

*e.g.*

```
self.lblRoll1 = wx.StaticText(panelControl,label = "0")
```

This is your problem -it occurs throughout your code.

An indispensable tool for solving these type of issues is  the [Widget Inspection tool](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool).

Also Id advise you to factor out the code for each panel into its own class (which would subclass wx.Panel). This will make it all much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Perfect! So for your second suggestion, for factoring out code. I would just need to `panelControl` and `panelBtn` separate classes, right? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @mitsu400: Exactly, I would also make a class for your roll (staticText, radioButton combo..) rather then having to repeat this code 6 times.  Then you could use a loop to add to add six of these custom widgets to your...

Comment: @mitsu400: If my answer solved your problem, then you should consider accepting it.

Comment: Also, I was not aware that I could loop GUI elements..?

Comment: The problem (I think) with that, is that I need to select each `lblRoll#` seperatly for doing math later on. Would there still be a way to do this?

Comment: @mitsu400: Yes it can be done, in fact there are a number of ways to do it. One way is to store references to you widgets in a dictionary or list. Another way (if all of these widgets are going to be bound to the same event handler) is use the widgets label attributes to identify them in their event handler, this way you don't need to store any references to them. There are also other methods...